# A way to free up space in array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array `int dom[][] = new int[28][3];`, which I move to a different array. How can I free up that array's space? I'm getting high cpu warnings while running it on the android emulator.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you don't have to free array manually, Garbage collector will clear memory for you. You can just set you object to null: `dom = null`.

CPU warnings doesn't have anything with this, android emulator has some CPU intensive operations at startup, so your processor will be at 100% some time until emulator starts.

Answer (score 2):

set dom to null. so that  it will get freed up when the next Garbage collector runs.

Comment: Just set the dom = null , this will make the dom array variable eligible for Garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything: **if** the array is not reachable any more because you don't have a reference to it, it will be garbage collected (setting the reference to null won't make a difference).

Typically, if this is a local variable and you don't return it from the method where it is declared, it will become eligible for GC as soon as the method exits (i.e. as soon as the array is out of scope).

And if you are "getting high cpu warnings", then the problem is with CPU, not memory.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting high cpu warnings while running the android emulator?

It could be anything.  However, I'm guessing that you've added some explicit `System.gc()` calls in an attempt to free up space a bit earlier.

Don't do that!

The virtual machine generally knows when there is lots of potential garbage to collect ... and that is the best time to run the GC.  And you can be assured that the GC will be run immediately the JVM decides to bail out with an OOME.

If you call `System.gc()` yourself, the chances are that you will just cause the VM to waste CPU cycles to little useful effect.

---

In most situations, the best strategy is to let the VM schedule the GC as required.  Null'ing references can help, but it is usually unnecessary.  (And frankly a 28x3 array of integers takes very little space, and is probably not worth nulling.)